# Windows SSH client that supports certificates

Tags: windows, ssh

[SSH certificates](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu) are an interesting SSH feature that is relatively new. Certificates are a bit more than just SSH public key authentication.

Is there a Windows SSH client that supports certificates?

I'm initially mostly interested in host certificates, and will be interested in user certificates in the future.

Comment: Have you checked [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) or [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/)? They should support certificates. I will confirm it and post an answer when I get to a PC

Comment: @Timmy - yes I have checked. Just to be clear, I am asking about certificates, not keys.

Comment: Please help me with this. What is SSH Certificate exactly? The link that you have shared, implies the same concept as KEYS.

Comment: Something that I wanted to mention though is that Microsoft is planning to add SSH support to their power shell, that is the first official support of Microsoft for SSH

Comment: @Musa - read the link again, it does explain the difference. In short, SSH certificates save you having to include your public key in authorized_keys on all the hosts you connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this question is a bit old, but [ZOC SSH Client](https://www.emtec.com/zoc/index.html) should support SSH private keys and also certificate keys. Its feature page says it's built on openssh 6.6 and certificate keys are part of openssh since 5.6 and the feature [page lists](https://www.emtec.com/zoc/features.html) certificates as a SSH login method.

Also, meanwhile there is another [OpenSSH implementation](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) too, that's not CygWin.

Comment: Great info!  But I think that certificate keys came to OpenSSH just a little (six months) earlier, in OpenSSH 5.4 (rather than 5.6).   Confirmed this in the 5.4 release notes (that are linked at the following reference), after noticing the note on this added to the "Features" table, "CA Certificates" column, "OpenSSH" row of the Wikipedia SSH clients comparison: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients.  Follow the footnote link from the table (it's presently footnote numbered "f") for the Release Notes pointer.

Answer (score 1):

For most of my windows SSH work, I use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). It's pretty much a mini linux emulator for windows (with a good chunk of packages available). It also comes with a really nice [package search engine](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) to check which ones are available.

One of the packages happens to be [OpenSSH](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fopenssh%2Fopenssh-6.8p1-1&grep=cert), which should be able to handle any certificate needs that you may have (I believe it's the only version of it to run on windows, and it is used by most linux distributions).

Comment: Sorry, I had let this sit for over a year. Accepted with reluctance because although this does solve the problem, it's quite limiting that cygwin runs in console windows, which are not nearly as nice to use as putty windows.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile Windows 10 ships with an official port of the OpenSSH client. The *ssh-agent* is an alternative implementation making use of the Windows LSASS credential cache.